# C# MS Equation Editor richtextbox issue

Tags: c#, richtextbox, equation, rich-text-editor

I have an issue with C# richtextbox and Microsoft equation editor. My goal is to read, modify and save changes in rtf file.
I followed tutorial below:

[C# Tutorial : How to insert Math Equation to RichTextBox | FoxLearn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7vRyx0ShVE)

I can read and modify equation in editor, however I can't update richtextbox after modification, modified value is not changed in richtboxtext.

[Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qCMD.png)

[Modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxkvq.png)

Update(F3) and exit in equation editor doesn't cause change in richtextbox.
However when I double click equation in editor there is changed value.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Panel.Views
{
    public partial class Axis : Form
    {
        public Axis()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = Panel.Properties.Resources.Plot1_x_axis;
        }
    }
}


namespace Panel.Views
{
    partial class Axis
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(723, 431);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 36);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(770, 372);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            // 
            // Axis
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(822, 478);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Axis";
            this.Text = "Axis";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
    }
}
```

I would be appreciated for any help, hints or suggestions how to solve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When I use: `richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"File_path", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);` or

Comment: `string tmp = ""; tmp = File.ReadAllText(@"File_path");`

Comment: `richTextBox1.Clear();`

Comment: `richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = tmp;`

Comment: I have same issue, no changes after modification